# nansum only if at least one value is not nan - numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I want to execute nansum function by row only if at least one value in the row is not nan.
So if all values in the row is nan, the sum should be nan not zero.

```py
a = np.array([[1],[2],[3],[4],[np.nan],[np.nan]])
b = np.array([[1],[2],[3],[4],[np.nan],[1]])
#a+b should be c
c = np.array([[2],[4],[6],[8],[np.nan],[1]])
```

Comment: Look at `nansum` code; it simply replaces all `nan` with 0, and does `sum`.  Interesting there's a note that in earlier versions, it returned `nan` in the case of all `nan`.  Maybe you could dig into the archives to see what that was coded.

Comment: but if all values are nan, I want it to return nan

Answer (score 1):

1.8 version on `nansum` https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/maintenance/1.8.x/numpy/lib/nanfunctions.py

was

```
def nansum(a, axis=None, dtype=None, out=None, keepdims=0):
    a, mask = _replace_nan(a, 0)

    if mask is None:
        return np.sum(a, axis=axis, dtype=dtype, out=out, keepdims=keepdims)
    mask = np.all(mask, axis=axis, keepdims=keepdims)
    tot = np.sum(a, axis=axis, dtype=dtype, out=out, keepdims=keepdims)
    if np.any(mask):
        tot = _copyto(tot, np.nan, mask)
        warnings.warn("In Numpy 1.9 the sum along empty slices will be zero.",
                      FutureWarning)
    return tot
```

The current version just does the replace and

```
return np.sum(a, axis=axis, dtype=dtype, out=out, keepdims=keepdims)
```

So you could do

```
a, mask = np.lib.nanfunctions._replace_nan(arr,0)
if np.all(mask):
    val = np.nan
else:
    val = np.nansum(arr)
```

or something fancier modeled on the omited 1.8 code.

Comment: sorry but I still don't get how I can use this code to add a and b to get c given in the example.. what is  "arr" and "a" in your code?

Comment: Did you look at the 1.8v of the function?  the one that returned `nan` like you wanted?  I'm just suggesting, without providing all the details, that you could adapt the earlier code to meet your needs.

Answer (score -1):

The following code works but may or may not be what you're after in the long run:

```py
c = np.array([[np.nansum(x) if not np.all(np.isnan(x)) 
                            else np.nan 
               for x in np.array([a,b]).T[0]]]).T
```

Comment: what do you mean by not in the long run? Because it includes loop function (too slow?)

Comment: Why provide an answer if `may not be what OP's after in the long run`?

Comment: Sorry. I meant that the data structure provided is a bit weird. Why are each of the items nested 1 deep? Is this really the data that is going to be used? Also yes, the comprehension is slower than a pure numpy solution. Thanks though to everybody downvoting a working solution.